# COUNTA and INDIRECT in VBA for assigning variables

Tags: excel, vba, excel-indirect

I have a variable `num_d` which I've declared as an Integer. Its value should be the result of this worksheet formula:

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"& 2*),INDIRECT("Sheet1!B"& 2*),INDIRECT("Sheet1!C"& 2*))
```

*2 is just an example here - this value could be anything.

I'd like to avoid populating a cell with the result of this formula, and instead assign `num_d` directly.

How can I translate the worksheet function into VBA?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `WorksheetFunction.CountA` yet with 3 `Range` objects?

Comment: Not with Range, no. How would I use that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Worksheet` and `Range` objects:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim num_d As Long
num_d = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A2"), ws.Range("B2"), ws.Range("C2"))
```

If the row number is a variable, then just concatenate it:

```
Dim rowNum As Long
rowNum = 2

num_d = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("A" & rowNum), _
                                 ws.Range("B" & rowNum), _
                                 ws.Range("C" & rowNum))
```